# Magento unable to override an action of a controller

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I need to override the `stockAction()` in the `AddController.php` of `code/core/Mage/ProductAlert/controllers`. So I searched a lot to see how to proceed, and got this:

`/etc/modules/Totem_ProductAlert.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Totem_ProductAlert>
        <active>true</active>
        <codepool>local</codepool>
    </Totem_ProductAlert>
</modules>
</config>
```

`/code/local/Totem/ProductAlert/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Totem_ProductAlert>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Totem_ProductAlert>
</modules>

<frontend>
    <routers>
        <productalert>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Totem_ProductAlert before="Mage_ProductAlert">Totem_ProductAlert</Totem_ProductAlert>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </productalert>
    </routers>
</frontend>
</config>
```

`/code/local/Totem/ProductAlert/controllers/AddController.php`

```
class Totem_ProductAlert_AddController extends Mage_ProductAlert_AddController
{
  public function stockAction()
  {
    Mage::log('test', null, 'Test.log');
  }
```

But the action is not overriden and no Test.log has been created.

Somebody knows where I fucked up ?

Thanks.

Comment: Does /code/local/Totem/ProductAlert/controllers/AddController.php contain a reference to the Mage core file you're overriding?  i.e. require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Product_Alert').DS.'AddController.php'; - and are you sure your module is being loaded? (cleared cache, added die() etc?)

Comment: Yes it does: `require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_ProductAlert').DS.'AddController.php';` Cache is disabled, how can I be sure my module is loaded ? (It appears in `System > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are issue in your code:

- A `syntax issue` in ***Totem_ProductAlert.xml***. `<codepool>` should
  be `<codePool>` .p should be capital letter.

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Totem_ProductAlert>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <depends>Mage_ProductAlert</depends>
    </Totem_ProductAlert>
</modules>
</config>
```

- Require  to call properly include  ***Core AddController.php*** at
  `Totem_ProductAlert_AddController` class

```html
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 * Description of AddController
 *
 * @author work
 */
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_ProductAlert').DS.'AddController.php';
class Totem_ProductAlert_AddController extends Mage_ProductAlert_AddController
{
  public function stockAction()
  {
  
    Mage::log('test', null, 'Test.log',true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to copy paste the require_once in my question, the problem was with the codepool/codePool. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Totem_ProductAlert>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Totem_Custom>
  </modules>
</config>
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Totem_ProductAlert>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Totem_ProductAlert>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <productalert>
        <use>standard</use>
          <args>
            <module>Totem_ProductAlert</module>
            <frontName>productalert</frontName>
          </args>
      </productalert>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
  <global>
        <rewrite>        
            <totem_productalert_productalert_addcontroller>
                <from><![CDATA[#^/productalert/add/#]]></from> <!-- Mage_ProductAlert_AddController  -->
                <to>/productalert/productalert_add/</to> <!-- Totem_ProductAlert_ProductAlert_AddController  -->
            </totem_productalert_productalert_addcontroller>
        </rewrite>
    <helpers>
      <productalert>
        <class>Totem_ProductAlert_Helper</class>
      </productalert>
    </helpers>
  </global>
  <admin>
    <routers>
      <productalert>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
          <module>Totem_ProductAlert</module>
          <frontName>admin_productalert</frontName>
        </args>
      </productalert>
    </routers>
  </admin>
</config>
```

**Controller**

```
    <?php
    require_once "Mage/ProductAlert/controllers/AddController.php";  
    class Totem_ProductAlert_ProductAlert_AddController extends Mage_ProductAlert_AddController{
     public function stockAction(){
        Mage::log('test', null, 'Test.log');
     }
   }
```